# c:\Program is not recognized error while running vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff, microsoft-windows, error

I use windows XP for testing and running some programs. I installed Vim on the machine, but when I run `vimdiff` on two files, I get the following error:

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

along with errors [E810 and E97](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#E810).

Looking around the web, it seems that some variable in Vim is not quoted.

I think it's the `VIMRUNTIME`, but I'm not sure, and cannot find where to change it.

I'm using the default vimrc (`_vimrc` on windows).

As requested in the comments by @Ben, in order to run vimdiff I use the following command: `vimdiff file1 file2`.

Comment: The output actually makes me think you have a double-quoting issue. For debugging purposes, it may be useful for you to edit vimdiff.bat and remove the @echo off line at the top. Then edit the question with the output of running vimdiff, which should hopefully provide more details about where in the batch file the problem happens.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking vimdiff, as well? Also see http://superuser.com/questions/697847/cant-run-vimdiff-7-4-on-windows-7

Comment: @JoshPetrie I don't have a diff.bat file, just a diff.exe and a few .vim and .txt files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Getting a fixed Vim**

This specific bug was fixed in [7.4.103](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=v7-4-103) back in 2013.  Bram typically only publishes Windows installers on vim.org for major releases, so the installer there doesn't have this fix.

The [Cream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/) project regularly builds a Windows installer containing the latest Vim patches and provides them in their [Vim without Cream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/) download.  This is a commonly recommended resource for Windows users.

Using their installer and having it overwrite the common _vimrc will fix the `MyDiff` function.

**Avoiding the problem**

That being said, there's no need to use the `MyDiff` function defined in that `_vimrc`.  If you just create your own `$HOME\_vimrc`, then the system one won't be used.  This is what I do and have never had a problem using vimdiff on Windows without a custom `'diffexpr'`.

I'd recommend creating your own `_vimrc` anyway so you can freely customize it without risking it being overwritten next time you upgrade Vim.

Comment: If there is no need for a `MyDiff` function, why does it exist?

Comment: @elyashiv The _vimrc isn't populated with required settings.  It's just setting up some stuff that may or may not be useful to the user and providing some example settings.  The MyDiff function would fall in the example category, IMO.

Comment: For reference, here's another way: install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), then run `cinst vim` from an administrator PowerShell (command prompt will work too, but PS is recommended). To upgrade it later, use `cup vim`. (The commands are short for `chocolatey install vim` and `chocolatey upgrade vim`, respectively. There's also a `choco` shorthand for `chocolatey`.)

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem on my Windows 7 VM, I installed gVim, clicked the "install .bat files for commandline usage", typed `vimdiff a.txt b.txt` in a cmd window, and got the same error.

Here's how I fixed it:

- `:set diffexpr?` gives `diffexprr=MyDiff()`
- `:echo $MYVIMRC` gives me `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`; I opened this file and see the `MyDifff()` is defined here.
- I copied this file to `C:\Users\IEUser\_vimrc`, I started Vim and used `:echo $MYVIMRC` again to verify it's actually being used. We can now use this file to fix the `MyDiff()` function.
- On line 20, there's:

  ```
  let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
  ```

  The double `""` is wrong, this is probably a typo, so remove one:

  ```
   let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
  ```
- It still doesn't work :-/ I replaced the `silent execute` in the last line with `echo`, I notice that the command ends with a `"`, but I don't see an opening `"` anywhere. This is caused by the `. eq` part, so I removed that.
- We now have a working `vimdiff`! I still need to press enter twice on startup, though; I am not sure why this is... If I run the command that Vim runs in `cmd`, it seems to work just fine ... This may have to do with the way Windows cmd.exe works, but I'm not sure...

I'm not sure the above is the *best* way to fix it, but it's *a* way. **This is a bug in Vim**; you should report it as such. Feel free to copy this post :-)

Comment: `This is a bug in Vim;`  Actually, it's a bug in the _vimrc being installed by your installer.  At a guess, that's probably the [Vim without Cream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/) installer.  The problem should be reported there.

Comment: @jamessan I downloaded the Vim installer from the vim.org site at http://www.vim.org/download.php ... I don't know anything about Cream. It seems to me that the `_vimrc` file that this installer installs is part of Vim?

Comment: Ah, well that's why it's generally recommended to get the 'Vim without Cream' installer on Windows. :) It is regularly rebuilt whereas the Windows installer from vim.org is usually only built for major releases.  This bug was fixed in 2013, but the vim.org installer doesn't have the fix.